# EventListener UpdateReady not showing confirm on load when an update is actually there

Tags: javascript

`EventListener UpdateReady` not showing confirm on load when an update is actually there. It just skips the confirm alert and just updates without any notifications. It doesn't even reload.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(e) {
        if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
            confirm('An update is available, would you like to install it?', function() {
                window.location.reload();
            });
        }
    }, false);
}, false);
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: So you are just trying to reload the page?

Comment: pretty much yes but i want it to find the cache update, update it then prompt the user with a confirm box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(e) {
    if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
        if(confirm('An update is available, would you like to install it?')) {
                window.location.reload();
         } 
        }else {
                // No update happened
           }
    }, false);
}, false);
```

Comment: I have to private message you with the link because its private but it didn't work can you please take a look?

Comment: Yeah I can take a look

Comment: THanks how do i privatley send the link?